# call ofApp member function as function parameter

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I'm trying to understand and learn how to pass a function of `ofApp` to another function within `ofApp`. While passing global functions, or using a lambda function are easy enough for me to get, I simply can't get this to work.
The premise itself is simple, but I feel like oF structure makes it a bit more difficult than, and general answers towards the use of member functions as parameters are difficult to transfer.

What I try to achieve is a structure like this:

```
functionA (f(x)){ 
 //I do whatever
 f(x)
}
```

where `f(x)` can be any given other function of `opApp`.

.h definition

```
class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

public:
    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();

    int addition (int a);
    int operation (int a, int (*f)(int));   
};
```

And here's is the part of the oF "main" and the both functions.

```
void ofApp::setup(){
    operation(1, std::bind(&ofApp::addition, this));
}

int ofApp::addition (int a){
    return (a+a);
}

int ofApp::operation (int a, int (*f)(int)){
    int g = 0;
    g = (*f)(a);
    return (g);
}
```

Comment: `std::bind` returns an object, not a function pointer. You'll have to change the signature of `operation`.

Comment: i see. Looking at it from the other perspective, how do i adapt the call within setup if bind might be the wrong tool to do so? It would seem like im passing the object to itself in this case, no?

Comment: You have a couple of choices: 1. You can make `addition` `static` (it doesn't access any members). Then you get a plain function pointer, no `bind` required. 2. You can pass a member function pointer. Then you'll have to supply an object each time you want to call it (e.g. `*this` in another member function). 3. You can use `std::bind`, but have `operation` take a `std::function`, not a function pointer (or make `operation` a template to have it accept any function object).

Comment: great, thanks. static and operation(2, *addition) do the trick, simple enough!